# Can we compare whether different groupings of data improve model accuracy?

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic, model-comparison, rms

I have data from 100 different lab incubations of manure samples. For each sample, a 3-day incubation was done, measuring values (y-axis) against time (x-axis).
I want to perform a linear regression on my data in order to get values of the slope and y-intercept, which are important kinetic parameters.

Each of the incubations comes with a bunch of different categorical variables as well - things like "animal type", "manure phase", etc.
Here is an example:

| incubation | time | value | animal | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.98 | cow | solid |
| 1 | 3 | 0.97 | cow | solid |
| 1 | 4 | 0.96 | cow | solid |
| 2 | 2 | 0.98 | cow | solid |
| 2 | 3 | 0.96 | cow | solid |
| 2 | 4 | 0.94 | cow | solid |
| 3 | 2 | 1.00 | cow | liquid |
| 3 | 3 | 0.99 | cow | liquid |
| 3 | 4 | 0.99 | cow | liquid |
| 4 | 2 | 0.99 | pig | liquid |
| 4 | 3 | 0.97 | pig | liquid |
| 4 | 4 | 0.96 | pig | liquid |

I can perform a linear regression for each incubation:

| group | slope | rmse | aic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.015 | 0.004 | -27.680 |
| 2 | 0.021 | 0.000 | -43.190 |
| 3 | 0.004 | 0.003 | -29.546 |
| 4 | 0.014 | 0.003 | -29.504 |

However, I could also *first* group the data based on these categorical variables, and *then* run a regression on these groups. There are three possible permutations of groupings I could use in this case: "animal", "phase", and "animal+phase". Here is what the results from regressions on those groupings look like:

| group | slope | rmse | aic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cow | 0.013 | 0.015 | -67.662 |
| pig | 0.014 | 0.003 | -27.504 |

| group | slope | rmse | aic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| solid | 0.018 | 0.007 | -52.111 |
| liquid | 0.009 | 0.011 | -45.979 |

| group | slope | rmse | aic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cow_solid | 0.018 | 0.007 | -50.111 |
| cow_liquid | 0.004 | 0.003 | -25.546 |
| pig_liquid | 0.014 | 0.003 | -25.504 |

The question is, how would I be able to justify using one grouping over the other? Can I rigorously show that a particular grouping consistently returns lower AIC or RMSE values compared to the other groupings?

Comment: You want to model the relationship between *time* and *value* and you've taken measurements under different settings (these are combinations of *animal*, *phase*, *etc*.) You've estimated the slope & intercept for `value ~ time` on subsets of data, so for each setting separately, and you've noticed the estimates are different. Why do you want to pick one setting over the other?

Comment: Instead consider fitting one model to all your data. For example `lm(value ~ time + animal * phase * etc)` if you are willing to assume that the slope is the same no matter the setting. Or perhaps `lm(value ~ time * phase * etc + animal)` where *phase* and *etc* (but not *animal*) modulate the slope.

Comment: My goal is to make a simple predictive model, and I suspect "animal" may have a bigger effect than "phase" does, so I only want to include variables that I know have a large impact on improving modelling accuracy.

Comment: There is a difference between including/excluding a variable from the model and removing rows from the data. Example: `value ~ time + animal * etc` doesn't include *phase*. But you still want to use all the data points you've collected to fit the model because each observation tells us something above the relationship between each measured variable and the outcome.

Comment: Aside: As long as you are only "suspecting" something about the effect of *phase*, or lack thereof, you should probably still include it in the model. And let the regression estimate the size of its effect.